# How to configure point stick to scroll when some key is pressed?

Tags: linux, mouse

IBM laptops have this key on top of touchpad that makes point stick to scroll instead of moving the cursor when pressed. How to configure linux to do the same on laptop which doesn't have the physical scroll modifier key. Like for example configuring windows key to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Xorg uses an *input driver* on linux called `evdev` that can do something like that via a mouse button.

See `man 4 evdev`. Typically the feature you want is accomplished via `Option "EmulateWheel"`, although you will need a keyboard equivalent to mouse buttons 4 and 5.

Another approach is via packages `xautomation` and `xte`. The combination of these two packages can do amazing things. Essentially you can program `xbindkeys` to run `xte` with arbitrary commands. Try installing the packages and typing `man xautomation` and `man xte`.

For an example of something vaguely related,  and how it was solved with xautomation and xte, see: [*Where do I start making a linux input hack?* on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175192/where-do-i-start-making-a-linux-input-hack)